# How to use NamedPipeClientStream.Write with buffer size > 64K when serverName is not "."

Tags: c#, .net, named-pipes

I created two (very) simple programs, one with a `NamedPipeServerStream` and the other with a `NamedPipeClientStream` sending data to the first one, both running on the same computer.

When I change the `serverName` from `"."` to the actual name of the computer, I can’t get it to work when calling `Write` with a buffer larger than 65536 bytes.

On a Win 7 and a Win 8 machine, the call to `Write` silently fails, on Win 10 (1703) there is an `IOException` with message `The parameter is incorrect`.

The code (error handling removed):

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
  var buffer = new byte[1_000_000];
  long bytesRead = 0;
  using (NamedPipeServerStream pipeServer = new NamedPipeServerStream("testpipeF62E4E5B-2B9D-4430-A578-4E9302E6335B", PipeDirection.InOut))
  {
    pipeServer.WaitForConnection();
    int readSize = 0;
    do
    {
      readSize = pipeServer.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
      bytesRead += readSize;
    }
    while (readSize > 0);
  }
  Console.WriteLine(bytesRead);
}
```

---

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
  var buffer = new byte[65537];        // 65536 or smaller works
  new Random(42).NextBytes(buffer);
  string serverName = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("COMPUTERNAME");  // works with "."
  using (NamedPipeClientStream pipeClient = new NamedPipeClientStream(serverName, "testpipeF62E4E5B-2B9D-4430-A578-4E9302E6335B"))
  {
    pipeClient.Connect();
    pipeClient.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
    Thread.Sleep(2000);
  }
}
```

By the way, the same happens when the two programs run on different computers or when using other buffer sizes > 64KB.

The [MSDN page for WriteFile](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365747(v=vs.85).aspx) says:

> Windows Server 2003 and Windows XP:  Pipe write operations across a network are limited in size per write. The amount varies per platform. For x86 platforms it's 63.97 MB. For x64 platforms it's 31.97 MB. For Itanium it's 63.95 MB.

Is there some other limitation I did not find? Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Questions like these need to document the installed anti-malware product.

Comment: Why do you need a buffer size of > 64KB.   The buffer is temporary memory and you can still transfer larger files with a buffer size of 64KB.

Comment: @HansPassant Good point. The Win8 machine I tried has no anti-malware installed.

Comment: @jdweng 1. To answer the question whether it makes sense to use message mode. 2. Far more important: Maybe the limit is not 64K, but 32K, and it just happened to work with 64K, and it won’t work tomorrow with 64K.

Comment: The code as posted calls `.Write()` in a tight loop, since `bytesWritten` is never assigned. Can you verify it fails even with a single call? Otherwise, you may just be stuffing the write buffer too fast.

Comment: @JeroenMostert Sorry, I forgot the line that increased `bytesWritten`. Same behavior with a single call (plus a long `Thread.Sleep` to give the other party enough time).

Comment: Using the overload of the `NamedPipeServerStream` c'tor that allows you to specify the advisory buffer sizes, and explicitly using a larger buffer size (say `1048576`) will make the client report this buffer size (`pipeClient.OutBufferSize`) but it will still not fix this issue. It was worth a try.